# nftables disables/disconnects wifi interfaces

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, port-forwarding, iptables, nftables

I am trying to switch to nftables to set up some port forwarding. But when I enable the nftables service, it disables my wifi connection. Attempting to connect to an access point, I get `Error: Connection activation failed: (4) The device could not be readied for configuration.` If I disable `nftables` wifi starts up and connects no problem. To try to replicate my settings, I did the following from a working state:

```bsh
sudo iptables-save > iptables.conf
sudo iptables-restore-translate -f iptables.conf > nftables.conf
sudo mv nftables.conf /etc/nftables.conf
sudo systemctl enable nftables
reboot
```

On reboot, wifi interfaces won't start up. Here is `/etc/nftables.conf`

```
table ip filter {
    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        udp dport 67 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        udp dport 5353 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        tcp dport 5353 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        iifname "wlp82s0" ip daddr 192.168.12.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "ap0" ip saddr 192.168.12.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
    }
}
table ip nat {
    chain PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        ip saddr 192.168.12.0/24 ip daddr 192.168.12.1 udp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 redirect to :5353
        ip saddr 192.168.12.0/24 ip daddr 192.168.12.1 tcp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 redirect to :5353
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type nat hook input priority 100; policy accept;
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept;
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        oifname != "ap0" ip saddr 192.168.12.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade
    }
}
```

And if I run `systemctl disable nftables`, and reboot, it all works again. How can I replicate my working routing tables with nftables?

Comment: Nothing is dropped. So it has to come from NAT. Did your iptables rules work before? Or were they never tried on the current system? Also double check that there's no extra rules added: `nft list ruleset`.

Comment: This process replicates the existing iptables setup, allegedly, which works and is my current default state. `nft list ruleset` shows exactly what is there and in `/etc/nftables.conf`, since the daemon sources that file on boot. Is there any chance `iptables` conflicts with `nftables`? Can I have both of those running/working on the same system?

Comment: In fact, simply enabling `nftables` with an empty config, which should allow all packets through, disables my entire networking system it seems. I can't connect to wireless, etc. There is also no `br_netfliter` loaded. I am running Arch Linux 5.14.9